# Dynamically change root directory using regex

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following regex rule:

(?<=website-app-release-).*?(?=.domain.dev)

This rule will capture anything after "release" and before ".domain.dev" so if the URL is:

website-app-release-feature-testing.domain.dev it will capture "feature-testing" which is exactly what I want.

I want to implement this somehow within NGINX so it will change the root to something like this:

/var/www/$captured_string (feature-testing)

Thanks

Comment: Which part of the URL does the string appear? Is it the host name? If so, you can use a regular expression in the `server_name` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names).

Comment: Thanks, was able to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
server_name ~^website-app-release-(?P<sub>.+)\.domain\.dev$;
root /var/www/af-website-app/$sub;
```